# DataTable plugin not work when using CRUD operation using ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

My code have an error.I'm using **datatable plugin** ,it worked good when i don't do CRUD operation using **ajax** but it's not working when using **CRUD operation**...
Kindly help me out....Thanks in advance

Script

> > $(document).ready(function () {
>
> ```
>         $("table#tableSort").DataTable();
>     });
>
>     $("#loadingModule").html("Loading.....");
>
>     $.get("/Setup/ModuleList", null, DataBind);
>     function DataBind(modulelistfull) {
>         var SetData = $("#setModuleList");
>         for (var i = 0; i < modulelistfull.length; i++) {
>             var Data = "<tr class='row_" + modulelistfull[i].id + "'>" +
>                 "<td>" + modulelistfull[i].Module + "</td> " +
>                 "<td>" + modulelistfull[i].ProjectID + "</td> " +                    
>                 "<td class='text-center' onclick='EditModule(" + modulelistfull[i].id + ")'>"
>                 + "<i class='fa fa-edit pa-5 text-warning'></i>" +
>                 "</td>" +
>                 " <td class='text-center' onclick='DeleteModule(" + modulelistfull[i].id + ")' >"
>                 + "<i class='fa fa-trash pa-5 text-danger' ></i>" +
>                 "</td>" +
>                 "</tr>";
>
>             SetData.append(Data);
>
>             $("#loadingModule").html("");
>
>         }
>
>     }
>
>     // show the popup modal for add new Status
>     function AddNewModule(id) {
>         $("#form")[0].reset();
>         $("#ModalTitle").html("Add New Module");
>         $("#MyModal").modal();
>     }
>
>     // show the popup modal for Edit Status
>     function EditModule(id) {
>         var url = "/Setup/GetModuleById?ModuleId=" + id;
>         $("#ModalTitle").html("Update Module Details");
>         $("#MyModal").modal();
>
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "GET",
>             url: url,
>             success: function (data) {
>                 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
>                 $("#ModuleID").val(obj.id);
>                 $("#Module").val(obj.Module);
>                 $("#ProjectID option:selected").text(obj.ProjectID);
>                 $("#ProjectID option:selected").val(obj.ProjectID.Project.SourceCode);
>             }
>         })
>
>     }
>
>     $("#SaveModuleDetail").click(function () {
>         var data = $("#SubmitForm").serialize();
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "Post",
>             url: "/Setup/SaveModuleDataInDb",
>             data: data,
>             success: function (result) {
>                 if (result == true) {
>                     alert("Success!...");
>
>                 }
>                 else {
>                     alert("Something went be wrong!...");
>                 }
>                 $("#MyModal").modal("hide");
>                 window.location.href = "/Setup/Module";
>             }
>         })
>     })
>
>     //Show The Popup Modal For DeleteComfirmation
>     var DeleteModule = function (Id) {
>         $("#ModuleID").val(Id);
>         $("#DeleteConfirmation").modal("show");
>     }
>     var ConfirmDelete = function () {
>         var ModuleID = $("#ModuleID").val();
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "POST",
>             url: "/Setup/DeleteModuleRecord?Id=" + ModuleID,
>             success: function (result) {
>                 $("#DeleteConfirmation").modal("hide");
>                 $(".row_" + ModuleID).remove();
>             }
>         })
>     }
>
> </script>
> ```

table

> Module
>                   Project Name
>                   Edit
>                   Delete

Console Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVGas.png)

Answer (score 1):

This error appear when the table header had a column `<th></th>` with no title, but the row `<td></td>` for that did not exist in the table itself(in `<tbody>` of the table that means there missing a `<td></td>`).

So check your table header and remove a column `<th></th>` or add a row `<td></td>` in `<tbody>` and it should work.

Comment: I had this error and it worked. If you can post a header of the tabel and we can count on them for <th> and <td>

Answer (score 0):

i change the function now it worked...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            GetModuleList();
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var myformdata = $("#form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Setup/SaveModuleDataInDb",
                    data: myformdata,
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result == true) {
                            alert("Success!...");

                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Something went be wrong!...");
                        }
                        $("#MyModal").modal("hide");
                        window.location.href = "/Setup/Module";
                    }
                })
            })
        });
        var GetModuleList = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Setup/ModuleList",
                success: function (response) {
                    BindDataTable(response);
                }
            })
        }

        var BindDataTable = function (response) {
            $("#tableSort").DataTable({
                "aaData": response,
                "aoColumns": [

                    { "mData": "Module" },
                    { "mData": "ProjectID" },
                    {
                        "mData": "id",
                        "render": function (id, type, full, meta) {

                            return '<div class="text-center" onclick="AddEditEmployee(' + id +')"><a href="#" class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-edit pa-5 text-warning"></i></a></div>'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "mData": "id",
                        "render": function (id, type, full, meta) {

                            return '<div class="text-center" onclick="DeleteModule(' + id + ')"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash text-center pa-5 text-danger"></i></a></div>'
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });
        }
```